# Automake: building shared module which is not to be installed

Tags: automake, libtool

How to tell Automake to build a dynamic module which is not to be installed?

```
pkglib_LTLIBRARIES = mywrapper.la
mywrapper_la_LDFLAGS = -no-undefined -module -avoid-version
```

causes mywrapper.so to be installed to `pkglibdir`.

```
noinst_LTLIBRARIES = mywrapper.la
mywrapper_la_LDFLAGS = -no-undefined -module -avoid-version
```

causes *static* convenience library to be built instead.

The dynamic module in question is only used to run a test suite, and hence is not to be distributed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem. This is what I did, including the peeved comment to myself for future reference:

```
# The rpath is necessary because stoopid libtool won't build a shared library
# if it's noinst_, because what POSSIBLE reason could you have to do that?
TEST_PLUGIN_LIBTOOL_FLAGS = \
    -module \
    -shared \
    -avoid-version \
    -export-symbols-regex "<whatever symbols you need to export>" \
    -rpath $(abs_builddir)

noinst_LTLIBRARIES = mywrapper.la
mywrapper_la_LDFLAGS = $(TEST_PLUGIN_LIBTOOL_FLAGS)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `check_LTLIBRARIES` which is for test targets. According to Automake's [Uniform Naming Scheme](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Uniform.html):

> The special prefix ‘check_’ indicates that the objects in question
>   should not be built until the ‘make check’ command is run. Those
>   objects are not installed either.

It also generates a static library by default. I managed to force it like this:

```
check_LTLIBRARIES = mywrapper.la
mywrapper_la_LDFLAGS = -no-undefined -module -shared -avoid-version -rpath /tmp
```

You can also compile and run a test suite executable.

```
check_PROGRAMS = suite

suite_SOURCES = ...
suite_LDFLAGS = ...
suite_LDADD = ...

check-local:
    ./suite
```

Comment: If this works then it could be a good solution. Do you know if there is a `check_PROGRAMS`? Or do we use `noinst_PROGRAMS`?