# Automake: how to build shared library without installing it

Tags: automake, libtool

With Automake you can build a shared library (`.so`) like this:

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libyeah.la
libyeah_la_SOURCES = yeah.c
```

Then `libyeah.so` is installed to `$(libdir)` with `make install`.

When you specify the `noinst_` prefix (instead of `lib_`) to avoid installing the library, it's not built as a shared object (only an archive, `.a`). It seems that the library is never actually *linked*.

I need a shared object, without installing it, for project tests (a test plugin which is dynamically loaded by the test program).

I tried to add `-module` and `-shared` to `libyeah_la_LDFLAGS` without success.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automake: building shared module which is not to be installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8277478/automake-building-shared-module-which-is-not-to-be-installed)

Answer (score 0):

You can bypass the default `libdir` and install it in some other directory instead of `/usr/local/lib`:

```
make DESTDIR=/home/user/staging install
```

will install your lib in `/home/user/staging/usr/local/lib` (if you used the default `--prefix` at `configure` time).  Then (on Linux -- you didn't specify what your underlying platform is) you can:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/staging/usr/local/lib test_libyeah
```

to run your test.

Comment: I might be splitting hairs, but the questions was *"how to build shared library without installing it"*. Presumably so `make install` does not install it. Your answer shows how to install it somewhere else, which is a different question.